# Set `URI` Fragment in Java: Can `URISyntaxException` be Suppressed

Tags: java, exception, uri

I have a `URI uri` and a `String fragment`. Now I want to add the fragment `fragment` to `uri` (or exchange `uri`'s fragment with `fragment` if `uri` already has a fragment).

I can do `new URI(uri.getScheme(), uri.getSchemeSpecificPart(), fragment)`. Formally this can throw a `URISyntaxException`. How can this exception ever occur here? Can I safely suppress (`catch` and ignore) it?

Answer (score 0):

This exception can occur when your URI has illegal characters which are need to be encoded. You need to write a catch statement or add URISyntaxException to the method signature.

Comment: Did you find an example of such a character? This did not produce an `URISyntaxException` when I tried it: `fragment = "\u0000\f\t\r\n!\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_\u0060abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\u007F\u00AD\u0308\uD83D\uDE48";`. Not even bad surrogates did: `fragment = "\uDCFF\uD800"`. The doc about the `fragment` argument: "Any character that is not a legal URI character is quoted".